# The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' net core

Tags: wcf, asp.net-core, iis, connected-services

I'm having a .net core API and an EmailService as a connected service (WCF)
The EmailService is hosted on IIS (HTTPS); I'm trying to connect to the emailService with a Client Certificate. Everything is fine but i'm getting the

```
The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' error;
```

- **On the EmailService side:**

The SSL Settings are on Require SSL (Require),  the IIS Binding is on HTTPS

- **On the API side:**
  [image]

When i'm trying to access the emailservice by chrome browser, i'm getting a prompt for a client certificate, i'm picking the cert and everything works alright;

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if you can call the service properly since WS-security is not supported in DotNet Core. Anyway, this error typically indicates that the client’s certificate cannot be recognized by the server-side when establishing the `Https` communication. Also, if your client communicates with the server over `HTTP` and the server requires `SSL`, this kind of error also occurred.
[image]
The Https secure communication between the client-side and the server-side can not be established properly. As you know, the https secure communication requires the procedure of exchanging each other’s public key of the certificate. Therefore, the server-side and the client-side should establish mutual trust. In other words, the server’s certificate must be trusted by the client and the client’s certificate must be trusted by the server. The specific operation is to install the certificate in the local `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`.
Please refer to the below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication
Besides, the client-side should have access to the private key of the certificate provided by the client so that the https secure communication is valid. The specific operation is to add the current user to the private key management group of the certificate.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.